# Was JK Rowling inspired by the shoebill when she created Buckbeak?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Hagrid says to Harry about Buckbeak:

> Give him a nice bow. Then you wait and see if he bows back.

In this footage, we see people approaching a shoebill in the same manner:

Was JK Rowling inspired by the shoebill when she created Buckbeak?

Comment: I hope someone here has an actual answer, but, personally, the whole "bowing to a supernatural creature" thing reminded me of the [kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappa_(folklore)) (as reported in "The Usborne Guide to the Supernatural" (which is currently out of print, but there is a current [petition](https://www.change.org/p/usborne-publishing-bring-back-usborne-s-guide-to-the-supernatural-world) to bring it back!).

Comment: A lot of birds use bowing displays for various kinds of social signalling, it isn't unique to shoebills. For example [this page](https://web.stanford.edu/group/stanfordbirds/text/essays/Visual_Displays.html) says *'Male Mourning Doves may bow repeatedly and then lift their heads and coo when defending their territories'* and also *'Pairs of adult Adelie Penguins do bowing displays and exchange vocal greetings at "changings of the guard," thus making large colonies extremely noisy'.* For another ex. see the albatross courtship displays at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvpHBALOCAI&t=50s

Comment: @Hypnosifl That sounds like the makings of a good answer.  You might consider posting it as one.  It would only be speculation, but it could indicate that JK Rowling based her depiction of the hippogriff on the behavioral patterns of other types of birds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buckbeak is a hippogriff, a mythological creature that first appeared in the 16th century in the *Orlando Furioso* by Ludovico Ariosto. Rowling may have invented the name 'Buckbeak' but she didn't invent hippogriffs.

Hippogriffs are hybrids of horses and eagles, so I'm not sure where you'd get shoebill, except maybe for the tuft of feathers on the crown of head. Buckbeak, as he appears in the films, more resembles a harpy eagle.

[image]

In the book he is appears thusly:
[image]

Comment: I think the questioner is concerned with the bowing behavior, rather than the physical appearance.